Active Choice Parameter changes to String Parameter when job fails
I created a parameterized Jenkins Job which has two active choiced parameters, the second one is reactive (depends on the first one). Each parameter uses a groovy script to generate their values of choices.
The issue is that whenever the job fails, the those parameters changes or revert to String Parameters.
You can check from the images:
Before Job Fails:
Before Job Fails
After Job Fails:
After Job Fails
for info, the pipeline is the following:
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'Repository', defaultValue: '')
        string(name: 'Branch', defaultValue: '')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Input Validation') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (!params.Repository || !params.Branch) {
                        error "Repository and Branch parameters must be selected!"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I used Active Choices Jenkins Plugin 2.8.1 and 2.8.6, both has the same behavior.
What might be the problem?
I tried using Scriptler instead of having the groovy script directly in the jenkins job config, but it had the same issue.

When you define parameters in your Jenkinsfile, and you then run your job (i.e. execute that Jenkinsfile) -- the parameters that are defined in the Jenkinsfile override anything you did manually in the job configuration.
Since in your Jenkinsfile the parameters are defined as
        string(name: 'Repository', defaultValue: '')
        string(name: 'Branch', defaultValue: '')

this explains why, after the job is running, the parameters are ... strings.
As a side note, this will happen whether the job succeeds or fails -- what's needed is that it just runs.
Instead, try to define your parameters as Active Choice:
    parameters {
        activeChoice(
            name: 'Repository', 
            choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
            description: 'Choose repository to create the tool from',
            filterable: false,
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [ 
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: '''return[""]''' ],
                script: [ 
                    script: '''return["bitbucket-scripts",]''', 
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                ]
            ]),

etc.
